# Regular expression to select whole string consisting of all characters type

Tags: regex

I am learning about regular expressions and don't know how to write a regular expression for selecting a whole string which can consist of any character.

For example string like
" Happy coding_programming with-C"

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, both *positive* and *negative* cases?

Comment: show the input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Such a regex could look like:

```
.*
```

"." accepts any character (as comments suggest: the meaning of "." might be different; depending on the actual regex implementation you are looking at; but most often, "any character" boils down to "." )

"*" accepts that 0 to n times

Comment: `.` is not always *any* character, it depends on the regex flavor.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

```
.*

. is any character
* is 0 or more times
```

Comment: `.` is not always *any* character, it depends on the regex flavor.

Comment: For the OP,  . is any character, in any standard flavour

Comment: There is no "standard flavor" in the regex world. There are many different flavors.

Comment: For the OP,  if in doubt, look up PERL Regexp, as it is generally the standard flavor used or check out this link http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html